# ¿Por qué el abecedario español tiene ese orden?

Tags: letras, alfabeto

Es una pregunta que nunca me había planteado antes, la verdad. El otro día mi hijo preguntó si sabíamos por qué se decían las vocales «A E I O U» en ese orden y él mismo contestó *porque están en ese orden en el abecedario*. Entonces me pregunté cuál era la razón de que el abecedario tenga el orden que tiene. ¿Qué criterio se siguió? ¿Siempre tuvo el mismo orden?

Supongo que hay cierta correspondencia con otros alfabetos como el griego al menos en algunas letras pero ¿y el resto?

Comment: ¡Interesante pregunta! Dice la Wikipedia en [Alfabeto →Orden alfabético: pasado y presente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto#Orden_alfab.C3.A9tico:_pasado_y_presente): _varias tablillas ugaríticas del siglo XIV a. C. preservan el alfabeto en dos secuencias. Una de ellas, el orden «ABCDE», utilizado más adelante por los fenicios, se sigue utilizando hoy en día, con cambios menores, en los alfabetos hebreo, griego, armenio, gótico, cirílico y latino_. Parece por tanto que viene de lejos. También sería bueno saber como se eligió el lugar para las letras que no estaban presentes en el latín.

Comment: Gracias por las correcciones @fedorqui. Una duda que tengo: ¿Las preguntas así seguidas pueden ir en minúscula?  Creía que si pero puede que me equivoque

Comment: A mi entender, deben ir en mayúscula porque constituyen una oración en sí mismas: del [DPD en interrogación y exclamación (signos de)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C): _c) Tras los signos de cierre puede colocarse cualquier signo de puntuación, salvo el punto. Lógicamente, cuando la interrogación o la exclamación terminan un enunciado y sus signos de cierre equivalen a un punto, la oración siguiente ha de comenzar con mayúscula_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quizás existió una secuencia lógica, pero se desconoce; bien puede haber sido un orden arbitrario.**

Ya existía, de alguna forma, el orden actual del abecedario alrededor del año 1400 a. C. Traducido de [Wikipedia en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet#Alphabetical_order):

> Se desconoce si los alfabetos más antiguos tenían una secuencia definida. Algunos alfabetos hoy en día, como la escritura Hanuno'o, se aprenden una letra a la vez, sin un orden particular, y no se usan cuando se requiere un orden definido. Sin embargo, una docena de tabletas ugaríticas del siglo XIV a. C. preservan el abecedario en dos secuencias. Una secuencia, el orden ABCDE que más tarde se utilizó en el fenicio, ha continuado con cambios menores en el hebreo, griego, armenio, gótico, cirílico y latín; la otra, HMĦLQ, se usaba en el sur de Arabia y se conserva hoy en el etíope. Por lo tanto, ambos órdenes han sido estables por al menos 3.000 años.

**Fuente**: Respuesta de [Cerberus](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3036/cerberus) en [Is there a reason behind the ordering of letters in the English alphabet?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9589/134604) (Stack Exchange - English Language & Usage)

Comment: Gran aportacion. Gracias por poner las fuentes y referencias usadas. Hay veces que la gente se apoya en trabajos de otros pero olvida hacer referencia a esas fuentes. Espero seguir viendo muchas aportaciones como esta. Bienvenido!

Comment: @Diego No hay de qué; así es como debe ser, después de todo. Y gracias. :)