# How should I capitalize questions in a bullet list?

Tags: puntuación, uso-de-mayúsculas

When writing lists of questions, like the following:

> Debemos hacernos las siguientes preguntas:
>
> - ¿qué queremos conseguir?
> - ¿cómo podemos conseguirlo?

Should I be capitalizing *¿Qué ...?* and *¿Cómo ...?* in there?

I'm aware that list items should start with uppercase if the previous ends with a period; lowercase if it ends with a semicolon; or either if there's no punctuation between items.
However, **do question marks count as punctuation when it comes to capitalization of sentences in a list**? And if so, which type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: If you're already using lowercase with semicolons, keep doing that; if you're using uppercased full sentences ending with a full stop, keep doing that (but do not write a dot after "?"); if all the items are closed questions and there are no other sentences to tip the scale in any way, use whatever you want (lowercase with semicolons or uppercase without dots).

---

This is descrbied in the section *3.4.7.2. Otros usos de la raya* from the [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/dpd) ([first page](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fnXkCSrPbXcfizkA) and [second page](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UuXHWrTyklTJwHKS)), which RAE made available in http://t.co/LWyF2IRfWG in [an answer in Twitter](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/494403389963661312).

There we can find this explanation (I removed the examples for the sake of brevity):

> **3.4.7.2.2. En enumeraciones en forma de lista**
>
> Puntuación de enumeraciones en forma de lista
>
> La raya sirve también para introducir cada uno de los elementos de una relación que se escriben en líneas independientes. En este caso, debe dejarse un espacio en blanco entre la raya y el texto que sigue. A la hora de puntuar este tipo de relaciones, debe tenerse en cuenta lo siguiente
>
> a) Cuando los elementos que se relacionan son simples, es decir, están constituidos por una palabra o por un grupo sintáctico breve, hay dos opciones. Cabe cerrar cada uno de los conceptos con coma, excepto el último, que se cerrará con punto. Es igualmente válido prescindir de los signos de puntuación. (...) los elementos introducidos por la raya se escriben con minúscula inicial.
>
> b) Cuando los elementos de la lista son más complejos -bien por su mayor extensión, bien por presentar puntuación interna-, es preferible el uso del punto y coma. También en este supuesto cada elemento de la relación se inicia con minúscula.
>
> c) Cuando la relación se compone de enunciados completos, la práctica más recomendable es cerrar cada miembro de la enumeración con punto, escribiendo con inicial mayúscula cada uno de los conceptos.

So basically:

- **If you are listing mere words or small groups** of them you will always use lower case. Then, you can either list them without any punctuation:

> - fresas
> - tomates
> - ¿kiwis?
> - maracuyás

or separate them with commas and a final dot:

> - fresas,
> - tomates,
> - ¿kiwis?,
> - maracuyás.

- **If you are listing more complex items** (either because of their extension or because they already contain some punctuation marks themselves), use lower case and separate with a semi colon:

> Estas son mis tareas cada mañana:
>
> - comer muchos cereales;
> - recoger la ropa;
> - ¡quitarme las legañas!;
> - si es fin de semana, pasear en bicicleta.

- **If you are listing full sentences**, use upper case for the first word of each item, since all of them end with a dot.

> Notarás que estas preguntas tienen algunas cosas en común:
>
> - Usan una gramática, capitalización y puntuación correctas, o lo mejor que el autor puede.
> - Indican un problema claro que necesita solución e incluyen los detalles relevantes necesarios para ilustrar el problema de una forma que otros puedan reproducirlo.
> - Tienen títulos claros y descriptivos, normalmente en forma de pregunta.
> - Van directo al grano, son fáciles de leer y entender.
> - ¿Quién quiere poner algo más de paja aquí?<sub>ejemplo tonto para ver cómo queda si es una frase completa, tras la cual no ponemos punto pues [*tras los signos de cierre puede colocarse cualquier signo de puntuación, salvo el punto.*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C)</sub>
>
> Example taken from the help page of Stack Overflow en español, section [*¿Por qué el sistema me esta pidiendo esperar un día o más antes de hacer otra pregunta?*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited).

Comment: @walen good point! I will have to investigate that.

Comment: Yo pregunté algo parecido una vez en un [comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19085/por-qu%C3%A9-el-abecedario-espa%C3%B1ol-tiene-ese-orden) y @fedorqui mismo me contestó. En principio después de un cierre de interrogación va mayúscula aunque en algunos casos se pueden considerar partes de un único enunciado y la primera iría en mayúsculas y el resto en minúsculas pero separadas por coma o punto y coma: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C

Comment: @walen - I can think of two reasons to leave out the ¿ ?.  One, laziness; two, so many punctuation marks might upstage the content.  However, the example you posted in your question is not so bad because there are only two questions.  BUT: if you write your bullets as you showed in your post, then please do capitalize, because each of your bullet points is a complete sentence.

Comment: @walen done! I added an example for each case. As you see, and from the link blonfu provided, the final "?" can be followed by either nothing, a comma or a semi colon, but not a dot.

Answer (score 2):

Fedorqui's answer applies to English as well.  Since there was still some doubt, though, I will point out that a question **is** a sentence.  So if the item can stand alone as a **complete** question, capitalize the first letter. And use the leading question mark.